# Duplicating and renaming Google Sheet automatically

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating employee rosters for each division at my job that need to be checked daily. I have the roster and I would like to create a certain date range worth in a workbook for each division. I have the first sheet dated 090120, for example, and need to duplicate and rename up to 091220. Is there an easy way to do this without having to right click, duplicate, right click, rename on each tab? All the information for each one is identical and there are no formulas or anything like that. I am new to Google Sheets and am not tech savvy at all but there has to be an easier way to do this.

Comment: For documentation reasons please accept the answer that helped you the most or provide your feedback in order to modify it and solve your question.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution:

```
function duplicateSheet(){ 

const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
const src_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('090120');
const dupl_sheets = ['090220','090320','090420','090520','090620',
                     '090720','090820','090920','091020','091120','091220'];

  dupl_sheets.forEach(sheet=>{            
  var dupl_sheet=src_sheet.copyTo(ss);
  dupl_sheet.setName(sheet);                   
                      });
}
```

---

### Explanation:

- `dupl_sheets` contains the names of the duplicate sheets you want to create.
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is used to iterate over `dupl_sheets` and for every
  sheet name it creates a sheet that is a duplicate of `src_sheet`.

---

### Instructions:

1. Click on **Tools** => **Script editor**:

[image: step1]

2. **Copy/Paste** the aforementioned code into the script editor and **click run**:

[image: step2]

---

### Result:

[image: result]